# Inverted scrolling for external mouse

Tags: bluetooth, mouse, macos

I have an external microsoft mouse for my iMac. When I updated to Mavericks it inverted the mouse scrolling but I can't change it back. The mouse has a specific program that controls preferences within system preferences so changing mouse controls to "natural" within system preferences does nothing and the program has nothing to control this setting. The mouse uses bluetooth to connect to a usb connector so I can't connect the mouse directly through bluetooth mouse. How can I change the settings back to normal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "natural" scrolling is reverse of normal scrolling on a laptop. Switch off natural scrolling and let us know if that works.

Comment: @user3304179, just wondering if this solved your problem or didn't it.

Comment: I feel really stupid now. I already tried that fix but I guess I didn't notice when it switched back to normal.

Comment: chill! :) happens to the best of us. :) glad that i could be of help.

Comment: I had the same problem but I wanted to keep the "natural" scrolling on the trackpad, so I had to use "Scroll Reverser" app to set up my mouse and my trackpad independently.